# Ошибка при сборке приложения react native

Tags: react-native

При компиляции приложения выходит ошибка:

```
* What went wrong:
A problem occurred configuring project ':app'.
> Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':app:_debugApkCopy'.
   > Could not resolve com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.0.1.
     Required by:
         project :app
      > Skipped due to earlier error
   > Could not resolve com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.0.1.
     Required by:
         project :app > com.facebook.react:react-native:0.55.4
      > Skipped due to earlier error
```

Как понимаю он не находит эти дополнения. Как их установить то?